What do $du$ and $dv$ mean when used in an equation without an integral sign?
Main Question
How do I evaluate the expression $L\,du^{2} + 2 M\,du\,dv + N\,dv^{2}$, given values for $L(u, v)$, $M(u, v)$, and $N(u, v)$?
Background
While working on a personal project, I came upon this definition from Wikipedia for the second fundamental form (lightly paraphrased):

Let $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}(u,v)$ be a regular parametrization of a surface $S$ in $ℝ^3$, where $\mathbf{r}$ is a smooth vector-valued function of two variables. It is common to denote the partial derivatives of $\mathbf{r}$ with respect to $u$ and $v$ by $\mathbf{r}_{u}$ and $\mathbf{r}_{v}$. Regularity of the parametrization means that $\mathbf{r}_{u}$ and $\mathbf{r}_{v}$ are linearly independent for any $(u,v)$ in the domain of $\mathbf{r}$, and hence span the tangent plane to $S$ at each point. Equivalently, the cross product $\mathbf{r}_{u} × \mathbf{r}_{v}$ is a nonzero vector normal to the surface. The parametrization thus defines a field of unit normal vectors $\mathbf{n}$:
$$
\mathbf{n} =\frac{\mathbf{r}_{u} × \mathbf{r}_{v}}{|\mathbf{r}_{u} × \mathbf{r}_{v}|}
$$
The second fundamental form is usually written as
$$
\mathrm{I\!I} = L\,du^{2} + 2 M\,du\,dv + N\,dv^{2}
$$
where the coefficients $L$, $M$, and $N$ at a given point can be computed with the aid of the dot product as follows:
$$
L = \mathbf{r}_{uu} ⋅ \mathbf{n}, \quad M = \mathbf{r}_{uv} ⋅ \mathbf{n}, \quad N = \mathbf{r}_{vv} ⋅ \mathbf{n}
$$

The surface $S$ with which I am dealing is is a smooth, closed, convex surface parametrized as
$$
\begin{alignat}{3}
X(θ, φ) &= \sin(θ) ⋅ \cos(φ)\:& ⋅ &\:h(θ, φ) + \cos(θ) ⋅ \cos(φ)\:& ⋅ &\:h_θ(θ, φ) - \frac{\sin(φ)}{\sin(θ)} ⋅ h_φ(θ, φ), \\
Y(θ, φ) &= \sin(θ) ⋅ \sin(φ)\:& ⋅ &\:h(θ, φ) + \cos(θ) ⋅ \sin(φ)\:& ⋅ &\:h_θ(θ, φ) + \frac{\cos(φ)}{\sin(θ)} ⋅ h_φ(θ, φ), \\
Z(θ, φ) &= \cos(θ)\:& ⋅ &\:h(θ, φ) - \sin(θ)\:& ⋅ &\:h_θ(θ, φ),
\end{alignat}
$$
given a support function $h(θ, φ)$ and its partial derivatives $h_θ(θ, φ) = \frac{∂ h}{∂ θ}$ and $h_φ(θ, φ) = \frac{∂ h}{∂ φ}$, with spherical coordinates $0 ≤ θ ≤ π$ and $0 ≤ φ ≤ 2 π$.
I also know that the unit normal vector of $S$ at a point $P(u, v) = \bigl(X(u, v), Y(u, v), Z(u, v)\bigr)$ is
$$
\mathbf{n}(u, v) = \bigl(\sin(u) ⋅ \cos(v), \,\sin(u) ⋅ \sin(v), \,\cos(u)\bigr)
$$
From all of the above, and with the help of WolframAlpha, I've worked out that
$$
\begin{align}
L &= -h(u, v) - h_{uu}(u, v), \\
M &= \cot(u) ⋅ h_{u}(u, v) - h_{uv}(u, v), \\
N &= -\sin(u)^2 ⋅ h(u, v) - h_{vv}(u, v)  - \cos(u) ⋅ \sin(u) ⋅ h_{u}(u, v)
\end{align}
$$
However, it's been a while since my calculus education, and I can't remember what it means to have $du$ and $dv$ in an equation like $\mathrm{I\!I} = L\,du^{2} + 2 M\,du\,dv + N\,dv^{2}$ without integral signs. I've tried searching online, but haven't found a solid answer.
Are they just there as a reminder that, for example, $L$ is a product of the second derivative of $h$ with respect to $u$, without actually indicating a mathematical operation to be carried out on $L$? Are they saying I should integrate, with the integration signs being implied? Or do they mean something else?

In your definition $S$ is a smooth surface, so it is a smooth two-dimensional manifold. $du$ and $dv$ are examples of $1$-forms, which are also called co-vectors. These are elements of the cotangent bundle to a manifold. Essentially what this means is that on each point $p=(u,v) \in S$, the co-vectors are linear functionals on the tangent space. This means that they act linearly on tangent vectors to the surface at $p$ to produce real scalars. Expressions such as $du^2$ or $du dv$ are (point-wise) tensor products of two cotangent vectors, so they act on two tangent vectors to produce a scalar.

Just work with the symmetric matrix $\begin{bmatrix} L & M\M & N\end{bmatrix}$. See my free differential geometry text, linked in my profile. The $du^2$, $dudv$, … is classical tensor notation.

@smitke6 What does that mean, when it comes to evaluating the equation? What operations do I carry out?

These symbols $du$ and $dv$ are symbolics, they do not do anything for you. Their purpose is to get integrated. When you have a surface, and you want to integrate on the surface, you substitute into $du$ and $dv$ your parametrizations and then you can do the calculation.

To reiterate, you do not want to evaluate. What precisely is the goal? Standard questions are the eigenvalues and determinant of the matrix $\mathbf I^{-1}\mathbf{II}$.

@TedShifrin My goal is to find the principal curvatures of $S$, which I thought involves computing the second fundamental form.

As I said in the previous comment, you want the eigenvalues of the different matrix. I just wrote more in a comment on your other question.

Riemann, who invented all this stuff, thought of $du$ and $dv$ as infinitesimals.  Note that the product involved here is not the antisymmetric cup product used for differential forms, but rather the symmetric product.  While Riemann thought they were infinitesimals, nowadays some people think it is not polite to talk about the latter.  This seems to be the reason infinitesimals are not mentioned in the comments.
The charming phenomenon here is that there are two (completely different) ways of interpreting this notation: either in terms of infinitesimals as Riemann did, or in terms of differential forms, as I do for example in my course notes on differential geometry.

I look forward to constructive criticism by the downvoter.
